# Variadic Parameters v Array Parameter

Tags: ios, swift, parameters

I am struggling to see if there is an obvious advantage over which method to use when passing values into a function. My code below may not be the best example to explain the decision I'm trying to make, but it is, in my opinion, the easiest to understand.

**Variadic Parameter Approach**

```
func arithmeticMean(numbers: Double...) -> Double {
   var total: Double = 0
   for value in numbers {
      total += value
   }

   return total / Double(numbers.count)
}

arithmeticMean(5, 10, 15)
```

**Array Parameter Approach**

```
func arithmeticMean(numbers: [Double]) -> Double {
   var total: Double = 0
   for value in numbers {
       total += value
   }

   return total / Double(numbers.count)
}

arithmeticMean([5, 10, 15])
```

Is either of the two techniques preferred? If so, why (speed, reliability or just ease of reading)? Thanks.

Comment: On [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-16/swift-functions.html) they say variadic parameters "are simply a more readable version of passing in an array of elements. In fact, if you were to look at the type of the internal parameter names in the below example, you’d see that it is of type []" ...

Comment: The big disadvantage to the variadic parameters is that this wouldn't work: `let nums: [Double] = [5, 10, 15]; arithmeticMean(nums)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think there is no speed difference.Because,inside the function,you use `Variadic Parameter` just as `Array`.

1. I think that if the parameters count is small,for example,less than 5,`Variadic Parameter` may be a better solution,because it is easy to read.
2. If the count of parameters is large. Array is better solution.

Also know that,`Variadic Parameter` have some limitation:

> A function may have at most one variadic parameter, and it must always appear last in the parameter list, to avoid ambiguity when calling the function with multiple parameters.
>
> If your function has one or more parameters with a default value, and also has a variadic parameter, place the variadic parameter after all the defaulted parameters at the very end of the list.

Just from my idea.Hopes helpful

Comment: Note it has a disadvantage that a function may have at most one variadic parameter.

Comment: Since Swift 5.4 this is no longer a limitation. Swift 5.4 introduced Multiple variadic parameters in functions. SE-0284

Comment: Please remove the limitation. Now in swift 5.4, we can have as many variadic parameters as we want.