# passing unknown number of arguments in a function

Tags: swift

In my current project, I had to implement multiple functions to handle the different number of `UITextField` in multiple screens of my application.

I guess it would be more efficient if I can implement one function that can take any number of `UITextField`.

Is it possible to implement this surd of functions on swift 3?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Swift *`Variadic Parameters`* accepts zero or more parameters of a specified type. Syntax of variadic parameters is, insert three period characters `(...)` after the parameter’s type name.

```
func anyNumberOfTextField(_ textField: UITextField...) {

}
```

Now you can pass any number of textField.

```
anyNumberField(UITextField(),UITextField(), UITextField(), UITextField())
```

> Note: A function may have at most one variadic parameter.

For more info check this [Swift Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

There is another way you can do that is called *`Array Parameter`*. There are some pros and cons of these two methods. You will find the difference here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572738/variadic-parameters-v-array-parameter).

Comment: Never knew something like this existed. Great one brother!

Comment: @Md.Muzahidul Islam Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest would be passing an array of UITextFields:

```
func processTextFields(fields:[UITextField]) {
    for field in fields {
        // Process your text fields
    }
}
```

Comment: just what I wanted, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do so by creating a function that takes an array of UITextField as argument.

```
func handle(textFields: [UITextField]) {
    // do your things here by accessing each textFields like : textFields[0]
}
```

Otherwise you would just create a number of arguments that equal your number of text fields you have to do things on. 
Hope this helps :)